# What is the best way to write a test case for JERSEY web services?

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jax-rs, testng

I have a JAX-RS web service implemented with Jersey library and now I want to test it. In order to do that I'd like to host this service in my test by preinitializing it with mocked services.

What is the best way to host such a service and execute the test calls?

```
@Path("/srv")
public class MyService
{
   @GET
   public void action(@Context UriInfo uri)
   { ... }
}

@Test
public void myTest()
{
   MyService service = new MyService();
   service.setSomething(...);

   // How do I host it?

   // How do I call it?
}
```

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate of question 911805 -- are you asking for Jersey-specific or general JAX-RS testing tips?

Comment: I know how to test JAX-RS, but I'm trying to figure out how to use specific implementations (both Jersey and Restlet). If one of them will provide me with an acceptable solution - this will be my choice of the technology for our product.  At this moment I'm using Jersey, but, apparently, it's not providing me with a way to start only one specific service. It just starts the whole server with all the services it can find. I need a way to assemble the service under test with predefined mockups.

Comment: Have you found a way to assemble the REST resources with mockups? I'm trying the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

The new (revised) Jersey Test Framework which is part of the Jersey 1.1.2-ea release now supports the In-Process or In-Memory testing. In order to run your tests in-memory all you have to do is set the property *test.containerFactory* to *com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory*, i.e., run your tests as follows:

*mvn clean test -Dtest.containerFactory=com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory -DenableLogging*

For more details please go through the blog entry titled **Jersey Test Framework re-visited!** at [http://blogs.oracle.com/naresh](https://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey_test_framework_re_visited).

Comment: Does InMemory work with @Context? It won't set it for me. Causes it to throw exceptions. (And these get logged 4000 lines back whilst it rethrows a messageless and causeless ErrorMessagesException.</rant>)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the [Jersey Test Framework](http://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey%5Ftest%5Fframework%5Fmakes%5Fit) provides a solution for your requirement. It allows you to deploy a single service, and run all its tests. You could use the framework to run your tests against Grizzly Web Container, Embedded GlassFish and/or HTTPServer.

Please note that you could use the framework to run your tests against the regular web containers like GlassFish and Tomcat too. In case you have any more queries please feel free to send me or the Jersey users mailing list - users@jersey.dev.java.net an e-mail.

Comment: This framework does not allow to initialize an instance of the service in the same place as the test definition. It still requires to start the whole server via the config file.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but a JUnit extension like HtmlUnit or HttpUnit may be a good way to test a JAX-RS/Jersey service.  The test case can use XPaths to find expected return values and validate the returned value against the expected. See:  http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grizzly to host the services and then use the Jersey Client to access them. Take a look at the sample applications. For example, in the Bookstore sample you may find the TestSupport class and JerseyTest class (found in the jersey-test-framework) of particular interest.

I hope this helps.

(Unfortunately Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post until I removed all the hyperlinks so happy Googling!).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in to using the [Jersey Test Framework](http://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey_test_framework_makes_it)? Unfortunately it's still more integration test than unit test, but it might get you on your way.

Comment: Yep, I've seen it. This is THE problem that it's an integration tests. To avoid the integration tests, I should be able to create a real instance of the service class, initialize it with mocks and then pass it to Jersey to host it IN PROCESS.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I get it now. Right now the framework doesn't support IN PROCESS, bt we are working on it.
We will see that this support would be added in a coming version of the Jersey Test Framework

Comment: Thanks for the response. When do you target to have it?  This is very important part of the testing process - the "in process" allows developers to properly initialize the services/components and mock the related parts to isolate them from the rest of the system and enable the assertion of expectations.  There is no way around it.

Comment: I cannot give a dateline right now, but will see that this support is added asap. Will keep you posted once it is ready.